# Element is Statement Combined With If Statment Not Responding Properly on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Really need some JQuery help here.  I'm about to launch my laptop out the window.  I have come a long way with this piece of code an I think I am almost there but I am stuck on the last hurdle.

I am only going to include the pertinent pieces of code here because it is a very large piece.

I have a navigation menu for a mock solar system.  Here is the link to the larger external piece if you want to see the whole thing.  http://jsbin.com/zagiko/1/edit (please note this uses mostly CSS3).

I have a nav menu for the piece and when you click on the values in the nav menu the current script assigns a class of active.  That all works perfectly.  I built in a button to test the active state on click and the state changes are working.  But I need it to respond to the state change on hover.  I am not a JQuery person; I am learning.  It almost seems like the hover isn't working because it is responding to the data loaded when the page loads instead of responding in real time.  But I am just guessing.

What I need is an if statement that will respond to the live data (not on page load or when the document is ready).  The if statement should basically say if this div is active then this other div can appear on hover.  But if this div is not active then it cannot appear.

The current if statement I wrote is

```
if($("a.active").is('.uranus')){
    $('#uranus .infos').hover( 
        function () {
            $("#descriptionsp").fadeIn("2000");
        })
    };
```

The current script that runs when the site loads that sets up the menus is:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var e=$("body"),
        t=$("#universe"),
        n=$("#solar-system"),
        r=function() {
            e.removeClass("view-2D opening").addClass("view-3D").delay(2e3).queue(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("hide-UI").addClass("set-speed");

                $(this).dequeue()})
        },
        i=function(e){
            t.removeClass().addClass(e)
        };

    $("#toggle-data").click(function(t){
        e.toggleClass("data-open data-close");
        t.preventDefault()
    });

    $("#toggle-controls").click(function(t){
        e.toggleClass("controls-open controls-close");
        t.preventDefault()
    });

    $("#data a").click(function(e){
        var t=$(this).attr("class");
        n.removeClass().addClass(t);
        $(this).parent().find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        e.preventDefault()
    });
```

Really need you help.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I feel like what you are trying to do can be done in css. When the item is active, you should be able to define the hover fading effect with css3.

Comment: Hi @Huangism.  I am trying to do it with either JavaScript or JQuery because I already have to design an entirely separate 2D piece for IE after I finish this because IE can't handle the transitions.  When I get to the 2D version for IE I still need atleast some of the nicer feature to be able to work in IE because I will already been losing the 3D effect of the planets.  Plus I know that I am right there.  I just need the right JQUERY person to tweak this.

Comment: Your question is very verbose, and I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what you want to do. 

When I click, for example, "spirituality" in the menu, you want the related planet to respond to hover event, am I correct?

Comment: @ThesisDesign I think the answer is probably quite simple but because there is a lot to read I can't quite understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish. If you can simplify this down, it can probably be solved quite easily

Comment: Hi @JohnSterling.  Sorry for the lengthy explanation.  It's a large piece and I didn't want to leave anything out.  Yes, you are in the ballpark.  The current if statement that I wrote is attached to "spirituality".  When you click on "spirituality" it opens the plant ID div and it Info for that div and I want the hover event to trigger only if the info div is active/visible.  The others are just written as standard hovers without the "If".  The problem with the design without the "If" is that if you allow you mouse to glide over the design it will trigger the hidden divs.

Comment: One last note to clarify @JohnSterling.  The hover event should trigger if the info div for the planet is visible and you hover over it.  Then the description div should appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your block of code is only being checked when the javascript is loaded. At this time, the `.uranus` element is probably not active, so nothing will happen.

First of all, you want to move this block inside of document ready, otherwise your elements such as `.uranus` might not even exist yet.

Your logic is very close, but you need to move the if statement inside of the `hover` function like this:

```
$('#uranus .infos').hover(
        function () {
            if($("a.active").is('.uranus')){
                $("#descriptionsp").fadeIn("2000");
            }
        });
```

This way, every time you hover on `#uranus .infos`, it will only execute the code if the `.uranus` is also `.active`

Comment: Also it makes more reading sense if you do `if($(".uranus").is('.active'))` that's just my opinion, as that read if Uranus is active

Comment: @BrianGlaz YOU NAILED IT!  Thank you so much!  I think I was 2 hours away from smoking again.  It works perfectly.  Thanks to everyone else for your suggestions as well.  Again, Brian thank :).